# My ListView does not scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm trying to make an activity with a static header and a scrollable dynamic list. Here is the Layout:

```
<GridLayout
 android:id="@+id/GridLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="1" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">
    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listex"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use the height=0dp & weight=1 solution but the result is that when I add something to the list, it does not show any element.

If I use height= match_parent & weight=1 the elements are shown but is not scrollable

Please help, I tried a lot of combinations gettign no results.

Thanks.

Comment: for your listview, height should be match_parent, here

Comment: Are there enough items in the listview to scroll? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below codes :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="static header" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this list view and it works fine.
Maybe you don't have enough items in you list view, for it to scroll?

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set ListView weight to 1. or You can do like this.
just after u set ur adapter call this method and set adapternotifydatasetchange() after dat.

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

your list in the GridLayout  remove the parent of list view that is GridLayout it will scroll perfectly.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">
    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listex"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The vertically scrolling `GridLayout` should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView).You shouldn't put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` because the `ListView` class implements its own scrolling and it just doesn't receive gestures because they all are handled by the parent that is its `ScrollView`

Comment: The vertically scrolling GridView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView)

Answer (score -2):

Set to the linearLayout `weightSum = 1`